# TypeScript: how to use Reflect.metadata on inner property?

Tags: typescript, reflection, metadata

Here is what I want to do:

```
class MyClass {
  @Reflect.metadata("desc", "My outer property") // OK
  outerProp: {
    @Reflect.metadata("desc", "My inner property") // Error
    innerProp: string;
  };
}
```

The error is "[ts] Property or signature expected."

Why does the decorator work for outerProp but not for innerProp? Is there any way to do this without refactoring outerProp's type into a named class?

Answer (score 0):

The reflect annotations can only be appended to classes and class members, as stated in the [docs](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata):

> Decorators add the ability to augment a class and its members as the
>   class is defined, through a declarative syntax

The first annotation is added to the `outerProp` property of `MyClass`, which is ok:

```
@Reflect.metadata("desc", "My outer property") // OK
  outerProp: {
```

But the second annotation is added to a property of a typescript interface, not a class. This type definition won't be around at runtime because it is only a hint for the typescript compiler which means you can't add annotations to it:

```
@Reflect.metadata("desc", "My inner property") // Error
    innerProp: string;
```

To resolve the error, you have to refactor `outerProp` into a named class - there is no way around this since annotations can only be added to things which are still there in the compiled javascript:

```
@Reflect.metadata("desc", "My outer property")
class OuterPropType {
    @Reflect.metadata("desc", "My inner property")
    innerProp: string;
}

class MyClass {
  outerProp: OuterPropType;
}
```